# Find collision point between vector and fencing rectangle

Tags: trigonometry

it has been a few years since I left University, I have been unsuccessfully trying to solve this problem for a while now, I thought I might give StackExchange a try. (I'm making a game)

Given a cartesian area, the following information is known (please refer to chart)

- I know point of origin of a vector (x,y) and its angle
- Said vector is fenced by a rectangle, for which I know width/height (bottom left at 0,0)

I would like to know what the collision point (x,y) between the vector and the fencing rectangle

Any help/pointer would be greatly appreciated.

PS: The angle and point of origin of the vector will change so ideally the solution would work with any angle/point of origin

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and it works perfectly. Good job! Just a note for .NET users. You must do some fiddling with the "Y" calculation coordinate because in Windows a downward movement is positive. Also, if you are wondering why we toss the negative values, I think this is because if we get a negative value, then this represents the intersection if the vector were going in the opposite direction. You can also toss all values that return a true from Double.IsInfinity().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = \cos(\theta)$ and $b = \sin(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle from the $x$-axis to the angle of your ray. Now solve the four equations
$$
x + a t_1 = width \\
y + b t_2 = height \\
x + a t_3 = 0 \\
y + b t_4 = 0
$$
by computing (assuming a and b are different from zero) :
$$
t_1 = (width - x) / a \\
t_2 = (height - y) / b\\
t_3 = -x/a \\
t_4 = -y / b
$$

Among all the numbers $t_1, \ldots, t_4$, compute the smallest nonnegative one, and call that $t$. So it $t_1 = 4, t_2 = -2, t_3 = 3, t_4 = 9$, then $t = 3$. If all four are negative numbers (which can happen only if $(x, y)$ is outside the rectangle), then there's no intersection.

Assuming there is at least one non-negative $t_i$, the intersection point is at $(x + ta, y + tb)$.

Comment: Great solution. For any rectangle that does not have its left bottom point in origo, we can use the same equations but add the offset rx and ry to the right side of the equations.
 
Width + rx, height + ry, 0 + rx and 0 +ry and then subsequently this will slightly change the t-calculations.